# RESTful URLs, master pages, and PreviousPage woes

Tags: asp.net, javascript, asp.net-mvc, rest

I'm am building my asp.net web application using MVC (Preview 5), 
and am also using the Master pages concept.

My PageA and PageB are both content pages. I'm doing a form submit 
in a method via JavaScript from PageA to PageB.
PageB has its PreviousPageType attribute set to PageA, but when I access the 
PreviousPage property in PageB, it returns null.

Am I missing out on something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use TempData to store an object that your next request will need access to, this is how I avoid passing big lumps of data between sequence pages.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to access data of PageA in PageB.  You can wrap the data in an object and use the Model Binders as described in [Form Posting Scenarios](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/09/02/asp-net-mvc-preview-5-and-form-posting-scenarios.aspx) by Scott Gu to pass it to the controller.  You can then redirect to show PageB.

HTH,

Sunil Unnithan